# avahi: ping can't resolve hostname, but nslookup can

Tags: linux, dns, ping

`ping` tells me that it can't resolve some hostname ("ping: unknown host domain.company.local") in a URL but when I use `host` or `nslookup` on the same computer on the command line, the resolutions works fine (i.e. it's fast and reliable).

What could be causing this?

More testing: Firefox, `wget` and `ping` have the same problem. Pinging the IP address works.

OS: Linux (Ubuntu 13.04)

**EDIT** My `/etc/resolv.conf` reads:

```
nameserver 127.0.1.1
search domain.company.local
```

`netstat` reports:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

so something is running on this port (`nslookup` also reports it uses `127.0.1.1` as DNS server).

There is no `/etc/*inetd.conf`, so I'm not sure which application serves this port.

It seems that `dnsmasq` is used:

```
/usr/sbin/dnsmasq --no-resolv --keep-in-foreground --no-hosts --bind-interfaces
   --pid-file=/var/run/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.pid --listen-address=127.0.1.1
   --conf-file=/var/run/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.conf --cache-size=0 --proxy-dnssec
   --enable-dbus=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.dnsmasq
   --conf-dir=/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d
```

All the config files and folders are empty. Since `nslookup` says it uses `127.0.1.1#53` my guess is that `dnsmasq` works even without a configuration. But how does it know which parent DNS to query?

**EDIT2** Disabling `dnsmasq` as suggested by harrymc didn't help. So I ran `strace ping` which gave me this odd output (just the interesting parts):

```
open("/etc/host.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
read(4, "127.0.0.1\tlocalhost\n#127.0.1.1\ta"..., 4096) = 613
...
open("/lib/libnss_mdns4_minimal.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
read(4, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\0\f\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
...
mmap(NULL, 2105560, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 4, 0) = 0x7f7829b00000
...
socket(PF_FILE, SOCK_STREAM, 0)         = 4
fcntl(4, F_GETFD)                       = 0
fcntl(4, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_FILE, path="/var/run/avahi-daemon/socket"}, 110) = 0
fcntl(4, F_GETFL)                       = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFSOCK|0777, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f782a4f8000
lseek(4, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek)
write(4, "RESOLVE-HOSTNAME-IPV4 domain.com"..., 44) = 44
read(4, "-15 Timeout reached\n", 4096)  = 20
```

So `ping` looks in `/etc/hosts` which makes sense. Then it loads and `mmap()`s `/lib/libnss_mdns4_minimal.so.2` which makes sense as well.

But then it talks to avahi!?

Which led me to this forum post: [ping doesn't make a dns request](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/ping-doesn%27t-make-a-dns-request-933059/).

My `/etc/nsswitch.conf` also contains this line:

```
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4
```

If I `ping` a working address, I see that the process also loads `/lib/libnss_mdns4_minimal.so.2` but then, it does a DNS query via port 53.

So my guess is now that `/lib/libnss_mdns4_minimal.so.2` is somehow noticing that the IP address ends with `.local` and not with `.com` and then the `[NOTFOUND=return]` is triggered.

How do I fix this?

Comment: What's in your `/etc/resolv.conf`?

Comment: Which is correct and which is incorrect? *Should* the hostname resolve or shouldn't it? You didn't tell us which of two completely different problems you have. (And if it *should* resolve, explain in as much detail as possible *how* and *why* it should resolve, as that will likely lead to the explanation of why it doesn't.)

Comment: ... and what your HTTP proxy settings are for Chrome, Firefox, and `wget`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: I'm expecting resolution to work. What I don't understand how `nslookup` or `host` can resolve the name and anything else on the system can't.

Comment: @JdeBP: I'm using a proxy.pac that returns `DIRECT` for this URL. But it never gets so far; all the programs already fail to resolve the host name (no matter whether I configure to use a proxy or not).

Comment: @AaronDigulla What is different about this name compared to names that work?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: It's a local/internal name (ie. something that only our internal DNS server knows about). I could imaging that web browser use special DNS lookup code but how can the command line tools `ping` and `nslookup` disagree?

Comment: Under Windows I know that nslookup opens an Internet connection on the DNS port and issues an external query, whereas ping uses the locally installed DNS client service, which from what you say appears to be dnsmasq. I don't know enough about Linux and dnsmasq, but evidently there is a problem with it. Why do you need dnsmasq? The [Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Dnsmasq) talks about possible conflicts when installing it.

Comment: Can programs like Chrome, `ping`, `telnet` and `wget` resolve *any* hostnames (e.g., Internet sites)?

Comment: @Scott: Yes. Most sites work, only this one doesn't.

Comment: @harrymc: I didn't install it. I just installed Kubuntu. I was surprised to find dnsmasq on my system and I know nothing about it. On my system, NetworkManager starts the process.

Comment: The linked doc specifically says the conflicts are with Network Manager, and recommends to install dnsmasq-base but not dnsmasq. You might try uninstalling it but keeping dnsmasq-base.

Comment: @harrymc: That is already the case. I only have `dnsmasq-base` installed.

Comment: If you are not doing connection sharing with other devices or VMs thru your computer, you could turn off dnsmasq in Network Manager. Edit `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and comment the `dns=dnsmasq` line (put a # in front of it) then do a `sudo restart network-manager`. That will turn off the local resolver. ([source](https://www.stgraber.org/2012/02/24/dns-in-ubuntu-12-04/))

Comment: @harrymc: Thanks, that works as well but I like the "fix the AVAHI config" approach better. Still, turn it into answer and I'll upvote it.

Comment: @AaronDigulla: Done.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As described in detail in [this blog post](http://www.lowlevelmanager.com/2011/09/fix-linux-dns-issues-with-local.html), you need to edit `/etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf`:

```
[server]
domain-name=.alocal
```

This binds the daemon to the domain `.alocal` instead of the default `.local`.

and restart the daemon with:

```
sudo service avahi-daemon restart
```

Note from the blog post:

> You may need to flush the DNS,mDNS and resolver cache, as well as restart your web browsers to clear their internal cache.

After that, `ping` and `nslookup` started to agree.

Thanks to [harrymc](https://superuser.com/users/8672/harrymc) for getting me on the right track.

Comment: Also note, `ping` will use nss, `nslookup` does not. (it uses lwres and, well, bind, to talk to directly with a resolver)

Comment: For me it does more sense to configure it right instead of disabling it for local.

Comment: @otakun85: And how would I do that?

Comment: @AaronDigulla You configured it and the current highest voted answer disabled it for local.

Comment: This worked for me too, except I could not start the service with **domain-name=.alocal**, the error message suggested I should remove the dot: **domain-name=alocal**. This way it worked.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae: What was the error message?

Comment: Neat, that's my blog!  Glad it helped you!

Comment: This is amazing. Thanks so much. Battled with this for hours before finding this post.

Comment: OK and what if there is no avahi on my system...

Comment: @Petr then either your DNS server has it (and for some reason is configured to use it to resolve names) or someone has broken your DNS or you're wrong and you have avahi.

Comment: on avahi 0.7 I am getting ```service_type_browser failed: DNS failure: NXDOMAIN``` in case of changing local to something else

Comment: just remove [!UNAVAIL=return] in /etc/nsswitch.conf

Answer (score 11):

Modifying /etc/nsswitch.conf and replacing:

```
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4
```

by:

```
hosts:          files dns
```

worked for me.

Comment: This works at the cost of the [AVAHI services](http://www.avahi.org/)

Answer (score 7):

Easy thing to do: Edit `/etc/default/avahi-daemon`

Change the line:

```
AVAHI_DAEMON_DETECT_LOCAL=1
```

to

```
AVAHI_DAEMON_DETECT_LOCAL=0
```

Restart the `avahi-daemon`, or kill it.

I don't like Avahi, and I don't use any of its features. If you want to truly disable avahi, modify `/etc/init/avahi-daemon.conf`, similar to the following:

```
start on (never 
          and filesystem
      and started dbus)
stop on stopping dbus
```

Comment: I don't care if you aren't supposed to put "thanks" comments here, I just wanted to express my thanks and how much time and energy you saved me. Thank you so much! I'm using a company VPN to do some emergency work from a mall and could not get some of our sites working despite everything I thought of trying. I wouldn't have been able to figure this out on my own, that's for sure...

Answer (score 6):

it seems .local address can't be access in ubuntu.

a solution is to edit `/etc/nsswitch.conf` and change this line :

```
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
```

by this :

```
hosts:          files dns
```

Comment: This sort of worked for me.  In my case, the hosts line had "files resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns" and changing it to "files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns" worked.  Thanks for the pointer in the right direction.

Comment: Tried teh other answers above, disabled avahi (which is a relief) and still had the problem.  This answer solved it for me.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you are not doing connection sharing with other devices or VMs thru your computer, you could turn off dnsmasq in Network Manager.

Edit `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and comment the line (put a # in front of it) :

```
dns=dnsmasq
```

Then do :

```
sudo restart network-manager
```

That will turn off the local resolver.

Source: [DNS in Ubuntu 12.04](https://www.stgraber.org/2012/02/24/dns-in-ubuntu-12-04/).

Comment: Who downvoted in 2022 an answer from 2014?

Answer (score 1):

> So my guess is now that /lib/libnss_mdns4_minimal.so.2 is somehow
>   noticing that the IP address ends with .local and not with .com and
>   then the [NOTFOUND=return] is triggered.
>
> How do I fix this?

Pretty good guess, but the other answers are overkill. The simple solution is to remove the bit that is indeed triggered, i.e. remove *just* `[NOTFOUND=return]`.

Removing it means that if `mdns4_minimal` returns `NOTFOUND`, the next entry on the resolver list is used. This is the normal behavior; `[NOTFOUND=return]` is an optimization to fail quicker on unknown names but it assumes all `.local` names are in mDNS.

Answer (score 0):

I had an interesting case with the same symptoms (ping, mount etc. not working, but host, dig working). Check permissions on **/etc/resolv.conf** file. In my case, someone changed it and I did not have rights to read it (although `cat /etc/resolv.conf` and editing the file worked fine).

Anyway, strace was showing:

```
open("/etc/resolv.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
```

And as a result, it was trying to query localhost (127.0.0.1) instead of a IP of nameserver from the resolv.conf file:

```
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM|SOCK_NONBLOCK, IPPROTO_IP) = 4
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = 0
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLOUT}], 1, 0)    = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLOUT}])
```

And **tcpdump** was not showing any DNS traffic when pinging. All is working after a permission fix:

```
# chmod 644 /etc/resolv.conf
# ls -l /etc/resolv.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 111 Oct  3 09:54 /etc/resolv.conf
```

Another problem might be extended attributes of the file or any other access problem. In that case just delete the /etc/resolv.conf file and recreate it from the scratch.

Comment: Another problem that I had one one server was that all the root folders had lost their `x` flag, and thus a lot of binaries didn't behave properly. The fix was `chmod +x /*`.

Answer (score -1):

Another reason is the format of `/etc/hosts`. Make sure there are no spaces between IP and host name, instead use a TAB. After changing to TAB the host name could be resolved by ping.

```
127.0.0.1        test.local
         ^^^^^^^^ → Should be a TAB not multiple spaces.
```

Comment: it could be an answer but it is formatted as comment ...

Answer (score -1):

Setup avahi-daemon on Ubuntu for so you can reach hostname `ubuntu.local` from host OS

sudo apt-get install avahi-daemon avahi-discover avahi-utils libnss-mdns mdns-scan

Comment: Sorry, this answer is not related to the question. We're not asking how to install Avahi The question is how Avahi can break DNS lookups after it was installed.