# linux: No address associated with hostname

Tags: linux, networking, dns

Starting this morning, nothing resolved on any connection on any DNS, but nslookup is fine. There seems to be a disconnect between /etc/resolv.conf and all the tools that would use it. I can only access the internet using tor.

```
nslookup google.com ; ping -c 4 google.com
Server:         8.8.8.8
Address:        8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 72.195.166.25
Name:   google.com
Address: 72.195.166.23
Name:   google.com
Address: 72.195.166.20
Name:   google.com
Address: 72.195.166.26
Name:   google.com
Address: 72.195.166.27
Name:   google.com
Address: 72.195.166.22
Name:   google.com
Address: 72.195.166.24
Name:   google.com
Address: 72.195.166.21
Name:   google.com
Address: 2607:f8b0:4007:801::200e

ping: google.com: No address associated with hostname
```

Also interesting is that when I try to connect directly with an ip address, with links for example, it acknowledges that google owns the connection, and then refuses to connect. The error appears `Error loading www.google.com Host not found`

I tried the solution from [ping can't resolve hostname, but nslookup can](https://superuser.com/questions/704785/ping-cant-resolve-hostname-but-nslookup-can) but that didn't work, even though I'd recently configured avahi.

Here's my resolv.conf

```
# Generated by resolvconf
 nameserver 172.27.0.1
 nameserver 209.222.18.222
 nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

My other computer on the same switch is fine.

EDIT1

```
# Generated by resolvconf                                                                  
nameserver 8.8.8.8                                                                         
nameserver 208.67.222.222                                                                  
nameserver 185.121.177.177
```

made a new resolv.conf above, same problem

EDIT2

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Avahi#Configuring_mDNS_for_custom_TLD

nss-mdns was blocking it the whole time. Closing.

Comment: Are those IP addresses the addresses of working nameservers?

Comment: top default gateway
middle Privateinternetaccess.com dns
bottom unbound

This is a relic from an earlier solution I was trying where somebody said that they needed to put their gateway into their resolv.conf

Comment: And is your default gateway a working nameserver?

Comment: I don't know. I'm about to put in the openDNS resolver, the google resolver, and openNIC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if nss-mdns packaged with avahi is having problems reaching the exterior network. Check your /etc/nsswitch.conf for errors.