# My Raspbian (RPi3) cannot resolve names in my LAN

Tags: linux, networking, dns, ping, raspbian

In my LAN I have:

- 2 Windows PCs (**Peach** and **Cocotero**)
- My RPi3 with Rasbian

In any of my Windows PCs, PING works perfectly against any of the host.

But when I perform a **PING** inside my RPi3 it, it seems it doesn't resolve the names. It says:

> ping: Cocotero: Name or service not known
>
> ping: Peach: Name or service not known

However, **PING works** when I use the **local IPs** of my PCs.

EDIT: I found out that there is a StackExchange community for the Raspberry Pi. Someone, please move. Thanks!

Comment: `ping` in linux doesn't use `avahi`, and you have only avahi based hostnames, not real dns records. Possibly duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/704785/avahi-ping-cant-resolve-hostname-but-nslookup-can

Comment: Not only ping, I have a script that uses UNC paths and it cannot resolve the names. What should I do to make UNC paths revolve?

Comment: If you haven't set up some way for this to work, then it won't work.

Answer (score 2):

You should check the DNS settings at your Raspbian.

Do a `cat /etc/resolv.conf?`to check what your current DNS settings are.

I assume your router is set as DNS for you Windows PCs. Set the DNS server in `/etc/resolv.conf` to the IP address of your router. That file should look like this:

```
nameserver 192.168.0.1
```

You have to change the IP address to your router's address.

Comment: Hey, it seems my resolv.conf is generated automatically resolvconf. These are the contents: # Generated by resolvconf
nameserver 80.58.61.250
nameserver 80.58.61.254

Comment: If I change the file, it's overwritten each time I reboot/connect/disconnect the wlan0 interface. What should I do to make the changes permanent? Thank

Comment: I'm not very used with resolvconf. According to https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=57388, you could edit your interface in `/etc/network/interfaces` and add a line (I assume your interface is called eth0) at eth0: `dns-nameservers 192.168.0.1`

Answer (score 2):

Windows is doing this via NetBIOS and broadcasting/discovering names on your local network.  In linux, the `nbbd` daemon does something similar, when used with Samba/CIFS and `smbd`

However, `ping` and the other network diagnostic tools don't reference NetBIOS names in Linux, they do the standard DNS check (well, `/etc/hosts` then DNS....)

Easiest way to "solve" this is to set up a DNS server on your Pi and use a fake TLD to create a fake domain name and simply create DNS entries.  Go a step further and set up `dhcpd` on the Pi to give out IPs based on Mac addresses.

I do this - when I want to broadcast a file to my TV, I can point to `livingroomtv.my.home` and when I want to upload files to my iPhone (using OPlayer) I can point my browser to `iphone.my.home`